# Dropbox Python API: dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse: [404] u"Path '<path>' not found"

Tags: python, macos, dropbox-api

Having successfully run the 'Getting started with Core API for Python', I'm now attempting to print a file's shared link by doing:

```
def get_file_information(self, file_path):
     file_info = client.DropboxClient(self.sess)
     print file_info.share(file_path)
```

I've tried passing:

```
file_path = '/Users/augustoesteves/Dropbox/DSCN7334.mov'
file_path = '/Dropbox/DSCN7334.mov'
file_path = '/DSCN7334.mov'
```

But I always get:

```
dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse: [404] u"Path '/Users/augustoesteves/Dropbox/DSCN7334.mov' not found"
dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse: [404] u"Path 'Dropbox/DSCN7334.mov' not found"
dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse: [404] u"Path 'DSCN7334.mov' not found"
```

I must be doing something embarrassingly stupid, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropbox expects the request url to be in the form: `https://api.dropbox.com/1/shares/<root>/<path>` where `root` is either `dropbox` or `sandbox` and `path` if the file path. The `share()` method of Python API constructs the request url in the form:

```
path = "/shares/%s%s" % (self.session.root, format_path(path))
```

`self.session.root` is set depending on `access_type` value passed to the session constructor:

```
self.root = 'sandbox' if access_type == 'app_folder' else 'dropbox'
```

So your 3rd url should be correct. Check your `access_type` and `path`. Try to construct full URL and send a request manually.

Comment: It was because of the access_type. I had it set up 'app_folder' and completely forgot about it...